# Change Deep Options in a jQuery UI Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget, jquery-ui-widget-factory

What is the best way to change a deeply nested option in a jQuery widget after it has been created?

```
$.widget("test.widget1", {
    options: {
        deepOption: {
            prop1: false,
            prop2: false
        }
    },
    _create: function() {

    },
    _init: function () {
        this.element.append('<br>' + this.options.deepOption.prop1 + " " + this.options.deepOption.prop2);
    }
})
$("#one").widget1();

$("#one").widget1({
    deepOption: {
        prop1: true
    }
});​
```

The above code changes the `prop1` option to true and nukes `prop2`.  How can I change `prop1` while preserving `prop2`.

[Here is a jsFiddle for this.](http://jsfiddle.net/hWKxH/)

**Edit:**  I came up with a solution but it seems like kind of a hack.  Is this the best way to do what I am trying to do?

```
$.widget("test.widget1", {
    options: {
        deepOption: {
            prop1: false,
            prop2: false
        }
    },
    _create: function() {

    },
    _init: function () {
        this.element.append('<br>' + this.options.deepOption.prop1 + " " + this.options.deepOption.prop2);
    },
    _setOption: function (key, value) {
        switch(key) {
            case 'deepOption':
                value = $.extend({}, this.options.deepOption, value);                
                break;            
        }

        $.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})
$("#one").widget1();

$("#one").widget1({
    deepOption: {
        prop1: true
    }
});​
```

[Here is the updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MB3Mj/)

Comment: Looks like you're reinitializing the entire widget instead of changing options.

Comment: Well, this does run `_create` the first time and `_init` the second time.  It also runs `_setOption` (which is just inherited here) so it also changes the widget's options.  What should I do instead?

Answer (score 1):

The `.option()` as been extended in jQuery UI 1.9 to support setting partial nested options as  described in the [changelog](http://jqueryui.com/changelog/1.9.0/#widget-factory).

To change such option after widget creation, you can now use:

```
$("#one").widget1('option', 'deepOption.prop1', true);
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hWKxH/2/)</kbd>